# How to fix this layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting this output

[image]

when this is the result that I want

[image]

The HTML is

```
<div class="fl20">Ans&ouml;kans beroende:</div>
    <div class="fl20">Fullföljd</div>
    <div class="fl10">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl20"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="fl1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod<br><br></div>
        <div class="fl20"></div>




                <div id="ff" class="fl20">          
        Fullföljd från:</div>
        <div class="fl20">  
        <strong>1201191-2                     </strong>
    </div>  <div class="fl20"></div>

            <div id="wo" class="fl20">          
        WO-nummer:</div>
        <div class="fl20">  
        <strong>432432                        </strong>
    </div>





        <div class="fl20"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="datum" class="fl20">           
        Internationell ingivningsdag:</div>
        <div class="fl20">  
        <strong>2012-11-11</strong>
    </div>
```

And the CSS is

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
                color: #90002b; 
                font-size: 140%; 
                display: inline; 
                vertical-align: 3%; 
                margin-left: 1%;
                }

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}

.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}
.smallb{font-size: 85%;}
table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}
h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}



.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
        text-align: left;
}



.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 
.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}
.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}    

.sub_meny_search{
    position: absolute;
    right: 265px;
    font-size: 70%;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popuphandlaggare{ 
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: groove;      
    border-width: 2px;      
    padding: 0px;      
    background-color: #FFF;     
    font-size: 70%;     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 900px; 
    }

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}    
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}    

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 700px; color: #ffffff; }
.column1 {     color: #000000; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 600px;     border:0;     float: left; }
.column2 {     color: #000000;margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 80px;     float: right; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}
.f220 {
    width: 400px;
}
.f1450 {
    width: 600px;
    float:left;
}
.f1550 {
    width: 150px;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}
.paddedcell {
    padding:15px;
}
.b2{border:2px solid #efefdc;}
.inp_sel{width: 80%;}

.fl21{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:150px;} .fl455{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:120px;} 

.form-bg {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.form-bg2 {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.data-bar {
  border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;

}
.discount {
float:right;
width:500px;

}
.discounts {
width:900px;

}
.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}
.yta20 {
background: #eeefdf;
width:1100px;
}

.yta2 {

width:1100px;
}

.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
#table td { 
margin:120px; 
} 

#personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  #otherDetails {     float:right;     width:450px;      }

.th_rad_sort {border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; text-decoration: none;}

a img { border: 0; outline:0;}


.f { float: right;     color: white; }


.handlaggare { width: 1000px; }

div.data-box-nat{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}
div.data-box-pct{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 75%;
}

.horizontal-gradient {
    background: #1a2adb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%, #a1e6ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1a2adb), color-stop(100%,#a1e6ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a2adb', endColorstr='#a1e6ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    width: 1055px;
}

.horizontal-gradient-hlsok {
    background: #1a2adb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%, #a1e6ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1a2adb), color-stop(100%,#a1e6ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a2adb', endColorstr='#a1e6ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    width: 785px;
}

#topBar {width:100%; background-color:#EFEFDC; display:inline-block;}
#topBar h2 {float:left}
#close {position:relative; float:right;}â€‹
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Is using table not an option?

Comment: HTML tables would be a better option for this, since you're displaying tabulated data...

Comment: I want to move the text 5 centimeter. I don't want to completely redo the whole page from scratch. I didn't create this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get two block elements for top 2 large. You can use following css for that.

```
.blockelement{
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
 }
```

for bottom 3 columns create 3 float:left divs to create 3 column and add
rows to each columns again using blockelement. You have used waay too complicated code for that.
I think tables will make it lot simpler.

Comment: I don't understand at all. "Top 2 large" ? I don't want to start making the pagae from scratch with tables, I want to fix this thing.

Comment: Can you share it in jsfiddle. The css you gave is completely messed or incomplete. Look this. http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/awk7H/

Comment: Thank you for the help, I gave +1 for your answer. They way I could get around was adding some divs and then the text got more correctly aligned. When trying to do it with tables I just ended up trashing the page more, now at least I've got something that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

use this code with new structure

```
<style>
.data{width:800px; background:#eeefdf;}
.data div.hed{ font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; height:40px; border-bottom: #CCC 1px solid; padding:7px;}
.data div.group{font-weight:800px; clear:both; padding:7px;}
.group div.line{width:250px; margin-right:10px; float:left;}
</style>
```

and HTML

```
<div class="data">
<div class="hed">Grunduppgiffter</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class=" line"><strong>ingv</strong></div>
    <div class=" line"><strong>Ans&ouml;kans beroende</strong></div>
    <div class=" line"><strong>Fullföljd</strong>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class=" line">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class=" line">Fullföljd från:</div>
    <div class=" line">: 12313</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class=" line">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class=" line">WO-nummer:</div>
    <div class=" line">: 147754</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class=" line">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class=" line">Internationell ingivningsdag:</div>
    <div class=" line">: 5586764545</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>


</div>
```

and let me see what is your result

have a nice day